# ALTER FOREIGN TABLE and DISABLE TRIGGER not working

Tags: postgresql

I use **Postgresql 9.4** to synchronize two database, 
I use the extension **postgres_fdw** everything work great except, i have one table where i need to disable foreign key check, i use this statement :

```
ALTER TABLE foo DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

It's work great on my local database but on my remote database the following statement do nothing :

```
ALTER FOREIGN TABLE foo1 DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;
```

However in the documentation the feature is present, someone know if they are a limitation or a bug on this version of pgsql.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterforeigntable.html

Comment: if it does nothing, maybe there re no triggers to disable?.. please provide definition for both

Comment: It's a foreign key violation, on the same table on the local database the foreign key check is disabled and its work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second statement will disable all triggers defined on the foreign table on the *local* database.

To disable triggers in the *remote* database, you must login there and run `ALTER DATABASE` there.

Comment: No way to do it by query remotely ?

Comment: `dblink_exec` is to help

Comment: No. You could use [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) to do something like that if you need.

Comment: Thanks to you two